# Keep get alert and abort: shippable Integration with docker registry

Tags: shippable-ci

I am new to shippable, When I follow the instruction to deploy my image to my docker registry, I keep getting alert as follow:

[image: Build Result in console]

But I checked it all over and it's all matched:

[image: Configuration in my account]

This is my shippable.yml:

```
integrations:
  hub:
    - integrationName: ship-docker
      type: docker
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I forget to add the "ship-docker" hub integration to my project setting page. After I added it,  It is resolved. [image]